# SurfaceView getHolder returns null

Tags: java, android

I read other questions on this, but I feel like my architecture is a bit different, so I'm posting.

I have a game with one `MainActivity` and multiple views. Basically, there is one `LinearLayout` that fills `MainActivity`, and different views are set on the layout depending on the state. For example, `menuState` (menuView), `gameState` (gameView), `gameOverState` (gameOverView).

In my `BattleView` (which `extends SurfaceView`), I tried to implement a game loop. However, my `BattleView` cannot implement a `Callback` due to the fact `getHolder()` returns null.

How would I go on about fixing this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

GameScreen gs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.init();
}

private void init(){
    this.gs = new GameScreen(this);
    this.hideSystemUI(this.gs);
    setContentView(this.gs);

}
```

Then my `GameScreen class` contains `BattleView  class`, which is called when appropriate.

```
public GameScreen(Context context){
    super(context);
    this.init();
}

private void init(){
    this.ms = new MapScreen(this.getContext(), this);
    ((MainActivity)this.getContext()).hideSystemUI(this.ms);
    this.addView(this.ms);
}

private void newMapScreen(){
    this.ms = new MapScreen(this.getContext(), this);
}

public void addBattleScreen(BattleScreen bs){
    //this.bs = new BattleScreen(this.getContext(), ms);
    this.removeView(this.ms);
    this.bs = bs;
    ((MainActivity)this.getContext()).hideSystemUI(this.bs);
    this.addView(this.bs);
}
```

Well.. `BattleScreen` contains `BattleView class` and is initialized there. Then, `BattleView` class

```
 public BattleView(Context context, int monsterNumber, Hero hero){
    super(context);
    this.gameLoopInit();

    this.setBackgroundImage();

}//end

private void gameLoopInit(){
    holder = getHolder();  <------------- ERROR (null)
    System.out.println(holder);
    holder.addCallback(this);
}
```

Comment: Where did you initiate the holder?

Comment: global in BattleView class.

Comment: Did you ty to use getSurfaceHolder() instead of getHolder?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be a native method to SurfaceView class. No, I have not tried it.